# Untangling delayed definitions and substitutions

Tags: mathematical-optimization, argument-patterns

I am attempting to find the values of B1 and B0 that will minimize a metric. In the code below I define the metric and then attempt to calculate is by substituting in the current values of B1 and B0.  It didn't work:

```
gau[y_, v_] := Exp[-(y^2)/(2*v)]/Sqrt[2*Pi*v];
means = {-1, 0, 1};
vars = {B1, B0, B1};
p[x, v] = Sum[gau[x - means[[i]], vars[[i]] + v]/Length[means], {i, 1,Length[means]}];
f[x] = p[x, v] /. v -> 0;
ord = 3;
h = Table[0, {i, 1, ord}];
Do[h[[i]] = D[Log[p[x, v]], {v, i - 1}] /. v -> 0, {i, 1, ord}];
hSample = Table[0, {i, 1, ord}];
Do[hSample = hSample + (h /. x -> means[[i]])/Length[means], {i, 1,Length[means]}];
hMean := NIntegrate[f[x]*h, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
r := hSample - hMean;
metric := Sum[r[[i]]^2, {i, 1, 2}];
```

When I try to do this:

```
metric /. B1 -> 1 /. B0 -> 2
```

...MMa gripes about non-numerical values in the integrand because it hasn't substituted in the values I provided.

Ultimately I would like to use the FindMinimum[] and related functions on the B1, B0 space, but I haven't gotten that far yet.

I tried a bunch of different ways to set this up with delayed definitions, function arguments, etc but nothing worked.  Help, please?

Comment: In general, define your functions as `p[x_, v_]=...`, f[x_]:=...`, that is, with an underscore for your variables.

Comment: What are `gau` and `means`? Also, you show some confusion in the way you define variables and functions. Don't use `SetDelayed` (i.e. `:=`) to set the value of your variables. The errors do not arise from `metric` anyway. They probably come from the wrong definition of `p[x,v]`, which as you can check results alway in zero in your code.

Comment: @b.gatessucks  I know, but when I did that, it would try to do the integrals without substituting numerical values in first.

Comment: @glance  Sorry, those got lost in my cut-paste.  I added those definitions.  And I tried using and not using SetDelayed but I just got different specific types of failures.

Comment: once you correctly use Set and SetDelayed (SetDelayed for the definitions of `p` and `f`, as pointed out by b.gatessucks, Set for all the others definitions) you can see that the error comes from `NIntegrate`, because the integrand does not evaluate to a numerical value. Indeed, the variables in `vars` do not have a value.

Comment: also, there is no need to do a substitution like `/.v->0`, just define `f` with `f[x_]:=p[x,0]`.

Comment: @glance  I tried that.

Comment: Why on Earth did I get down-votes for this Question?

Comment: Without being one of the downvoters, you cannot throw 10 lines of code here, without even trying to break your problem down and expect us to give you a detailed explanation why it doesn't work.

Comment: @halirutan  Hmm.  I don't think my code sample is terribly complicated, but thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I believe that the OP could easily find the answer by him/herself by constructing a minimal working example.

Comment: @JerryGuern You code isn't Mathemtica-ish, and looks quite convoluted. You shouldn't use loops without a very good reason, and you should try to define functions when things depend on parameters

Comment: @belisarius  Yes, I only started using MMa a year ago, and I'm piecing coding practice together as I go. I used the Do-loop only because I didn't know how else to construct h.  I will study the code sample you gave me below.  In future Questions, maybe I should say explicitly that I invite feedback on my iffy code?

Comment: Mathematica interactivity invites you to test one expression at a time. Try to practice it. It's very difficult to straight up ten lines of code!

Comment: @belisarius   Yes, I do appreciate that it's difficult to straighten up ten lines of my code, but it's also VERY difficult for me to ask what I'm doing wrong in my coding if I only offer 2-3 lines of my code at a time.  In this particular example, there were SEVERAL things I could think of that I could have been doing wrong, and I couldn't guess which one I should ask about.  But I do realize I'm unlikely to get many Answers that way, so I hugely appreciate your taking the time to work through my ten lines.  I will study each line of your Expert version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to put you on a better path:

```
gau[y_, v_] := Exp[-(y^2)/(2*v)]/Sqrt[2*Pi*v];
means = {-1, 0, 1};
l = Length@means;
vars = {B1, B0, B1};
ord = 3;
p[x_, v_] := Tr@MapThread[gau, {x - means, vars + v}]/l
h = D[Log[p[x, v]], {v, #}] & /@ Range[0, ord - 1] /. v -> 0;
hSample[b0_, b1_] := Block[{B0 = b0, B1 = b1}, Fold[Plus, 0, h /. x -> # & /@ means]]/l;
hMean[b0_, b1_] := Block[{B0 = b0, B1 = b1},  NIntegrate[p[x, 0]*h, {x, -∞, ∞}]]
r[b0_, b1_] := hSample[b0, b1] - hMean[b0, b1]

Norm@r[1, 2]
```

Comment: Your NIntegrates need some work ...

Comment: Thank you!  This was exactly the help I needed.  I'm really trying to learn to code MMa well, so I really appreciate your taking the time to rewrite my bad code.  I know you're a pretty high-rep user, and I've gotten some great guidance from you before, so I take your advice seriously.  I'll look up all the commands you used that I'm not familiar with so I'll really understand what you've put together for me.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @JerryGuern Please note that your metric is the sum of the squares of `r[ x, y][[ 1;;2 ]]` only ...

Comment: Yes, correct, that's not a typo.  The metric as used in this run only requires the first two terms of r, but then I'll apply the optimized value to the higher terms of r, if that made any sense.